# Hide all Admin Notices and move on a separate page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, notices

I want to hide all 'admin_notices' from dashboard means everywhere.
I've a separate Menu name "Admin Notice". I want to move all notices there so I can manage them separately by user roles.
There will be 2 columns-

1. Display the full Notice
2. User roles dropdown

I'm struggling to find out with Codex Documentation. If Someone can help me I will be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you can run the action elsewhere on a different template or via a shortcode using [`do_action( 'admin_notices' );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/) however the only way to remove them from the default area (as far as I can see) is to hide them via CSS.

Below is a helpful code to remove all admin notices for all other users except the administrator:

```
if( ! is_super_admin() ) {

    remove_all_actions( 'admin_notices' );

}
```